How can I render subRows data for two different dropdowns based on subRows property for tanstack react table library?
I'm looking through the docs and was able to create a dropdown for subRows with useExpanded, but I need to create two dropdowns that filters data in subRows based on property 'isAnalysisRow'. So Dropdown 'A#' will show subRows data with isAnalysisRow = True and dropdown 'C#' will show subRows data with isAnalysisRow = False. How can I create this filter function using tanstack react table?
React table
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        toggleHideColumn,
        headerGroups,
        prepareRow,
        page,
        canPreviousPage,
        canNextPage,
        pageOptions,
        pageCount,
        gotoPage,
        nextPage,
        previousPage,
        setPageSize,
        allColumns,
        getToggleHideAllColumnsProps,
        getToggleRowSelectedProps,
        selectedFlatRows,
        state,
        initialState,
        visibleColumns,
        setHiddenColumns,
        preGlobalFilteredRows,
        setGlobalFilter,
    } = useTable(
        {
            columns,
            data,
            initialState: {
                pageIndex: 0,
                sortBy: [
                    {
                        id: 'startdatetime',
                        desc: true
                    }
                ],
                expanded: {},
                hiddenColumns: getHiddenColumns(),
            },
            defaultColumn,
            filterTypes,
            autoResetPage: true,
            autoResetSelectedRows: false,
            autoResetHiddenColumns: false,
            useFilters,
            useGlobalFilter,
            paginateExpandedRows: false
        },
        useFilters,
        useGlobalFilter,
        useSortBy,
        useExpanded,
        usePagination,
        useRowSelect,
    )

return(
 <Container id="mainHeader" style={{
                margin: 0,
                width: '100%',
                maxWidth: '100%',                
            }}>
                <MaUTable {...getTableProps()} ref={tableRef} style={{ width: '100%' }} >
                    <TableHead style={{ boxShadow: '0px 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%)' }}>
                        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                            <TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()} key={Utils.generateKey('tr')}>
                                {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                                    <TableCell key={Utils.generateKey('tc')} {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps(), {
                                    })} style= {{minWidth: column.minWidth, width: column.width, align: "center" }}  title={getColumnTitle(column.Header !== undefined ? column.Header : '')}>
                                        {column.Header !== 'Expand' ? column.render('Header') : ''}
                                        <span>
                                            {column.isSorted
                                                ? column.isSortedDesc
                                                    ? <ExpandMoreIcon />
                                                    : <ExpandLessIcon />
                                                : ''}
                                        </span>
                                    </TableCell>
                                ))}
                            </TableRow>
                        ))}
                        <TableRow>
                            {headerGroups !== undefined && headerGroups.length > 0 && headerGroups[1] !== undefined && headerGroups[1].headers !== undefined && headerGroups[1].headers.map((column, i) => (
                                <TableCell key={i} align="center" padding="none" className={!column.canFilter ? 'bg-white-non-filtered' : 'bg-white'}>
                                    {column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}
                                </TableCell>
                            ))}
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody >
                        {page.map((row, i) => {
                            prepareRow(row);
                            return (
                                <TableRow key={Utils.generateKey('tr')} {...row.getRowProps()} onClick={(e) => handleRowClick(e, row, row.originalSubRows !== undefined && row.originalSubRows.length > 0 ? row.index : row.id, selectedFlatRows)} className={getRowActiveClassNames(row)} style={checkUserIsLocal(local_state.user, row.original.issubrow) ? { cursor: 'pointer' } : {}}>
                                    {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                        return (
                                            <>
                                            {/* {console.log({cell})} */}
                                                <TableCell key={Utils.generateKey('tc')} {...cell.getCellProps()}
                                                    style={{ width: cell.column.width, minWidth: cell.column.minWidth, textAlign: 'center', alignContent: 'center', wordBreak: 'break-word' }} onClick={(e) => handleCellClick(e, cell)}>
                                                    {cell.render('Cell')}
                                                </TableCell>
                                            </>                                           
                                        )
                                        //return renderRow(cell);
                                    })}                                    
                                </TableRow>
                            )
                        })}
                    </TableBody>
                </MaUTable>
            </Container>
)

The columns
    const getTableColumns = user => {
        let cols = [
            { Header: 'Run Info',
                columns: [
                    {
                        Header: 'Sequencing Start Date',
                        accessor: 'startdatetime',
                        width: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 60 : 70) : 100,
                        widthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 60 : 70) : 100,
                        minWidth: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 60 : 70) : 100,
                        minWidthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 60 : 70) : 100,
                        show: true,
                        disableGlobalFilter: checkColumnIsHidden('startdatetime'),
                        sortType: (a, b, id, desc) => {                     
                            if (new Date(a.values.startdatetime) < new Date(b.values.startdatetime)) {
                                return -1;
                            } else if (new Date(a.values.startdatetime) > new Date(b.values.startdatetime)) {
                                return 1;
                            };

                            return 0;
                        },
                        Cell: row => renderTableCell(row, row.value, 'startdatetime', false, 'Start Date'),
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Sys Id',
                        accessor: 'sysid',
                        width: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 55 : 60) : 80,
                        widthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 55 : 60) : 80,
                        minWidth: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 45 : 50) : 70,
                        minWidthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 45 : 50) : 70,
                        show: true,
                        disableGlobalFilter: checkColumnIsHidden('sysid'),
                        Cell: row => renderTableCell(row, row.value, 'sysid', false, 'Sys Id'),
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Flow Cell',
                        accessor: 'wafershelf',
                        width: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 30 : 50) : 70,
                        widthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 30 : 50) : 70,
                        minWidth: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 20 : 25) : 40,
                        minWidthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 20 : 25) : 40,
                        show: true,
                        disableGlobalFilter: checkColumnIsHidden('wafershelf'),
                        Cell: row => renderTableCell(row, row.value, 'wafershelf', false, 'Flow Cell'),
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Chuck',
                        accessor: 'chuck',
                        width: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 30 : 50) : 70,
                        widthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 30 : 50) : 70,
                        minWidth: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 20 : 25) : 40,
                        minWidthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 20 : 25) : 40,
                        show: false,
                        disableGlobalFilter: checkColumnIsHidden('chuck'),
                        Cell: row => renderTableCell(row, row.value, 'chuck', false, 'Chuck'),
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Run Id',
                        accessor: 'runid',
                        width: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 75 : 90) : 90,
                        widthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 75 : 90) : 90,
                        minWidth: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 45 : 70) : 80,
                        minWidthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 45 : 70) : 80,
                        show: true,
                        disableGlobalFilter: checkColumnIsHidden('runid'),
                        Cell: row => renderTableCell(undefined, row.value, 'runid', false, 'Run Id', row.row.original.isanalysisrow),
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Project',
                        accessor: 'project',
                        //width: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 55 : 60) : 'auto',
                        //widthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 60 : 65) : 'auto',
                        minWidth: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 55 : 60) : 80,
                        minWidthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 55 : 60) : 80,
                        show: false,
                        disableGlobalFilter: checkColumnIsHidden('project'),
                        Cell: row => renderTableCell(row, row.value, 'project', false, 'Project'),
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Details',
                        accessor: 'details',
                        widthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 190 : 200) : (isBigScreen2 ? 300 : 400),
                        width: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 180 : 200) : (isBigScreen2 ? 300 : 400),
                        minWidth: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 170 : 180) : (isBigScreen2 ? 220 : 380),
                        minWidthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 170 : 190) : (isBigScreen2 ? 220 : 380),
                        show: true,
                        disableGlobalFilter: checkColumnIsHidden('details'),
                        Cell: row => EditableCell(row, editRef),
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Reagents',
                        accessor: 'reagents',
                        minWidth: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 45 : 70) : 80,
                        minWidthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 45 : 70) : 80,
                        show: false,
                        disableGlobalFilter: checkColumnIsHidden('reagents'),
                        Cell: row => renderTableCell(row, row.value, 'reagents', false, 'Reagents'),
                    },
                    {
                        Header: 'Amp Script',
                        accessor: 'amp_script_version',
                        minWidth: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 35 : 50) : 60,
                        minWidthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 40 : 45) : 50,
                        show: false,
                        disableGlobalFilter: checkColumnIsHidden('amp_script_version'),
                        Cell: row => renderTableCell(row, row.value, 'amp_script_version', false, 'Amp Script'),
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                Header: 'Expand',
                columns: [
                    {
                        Header: 'A#',
                        id: 'A#',
                        width: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 15 : 20) : 55,
                        minWidth: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 15 : 20) : 30,
                        widthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 15 : 20) : 55,
                        minWidthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 15 : 20) : 30,
                        show: false,
                        Cell: ({ row }) =>
                            row.canExpand ? (
                                <span
                                    onClick={(e) => {
                                        e.stopPropagation();
                                    }}
                                    {...row.getToggleRowExpandedProps({
                                        style: {
                                            paddingLeft: `${row.depth * 2}rem`,
                                            height: 40,
                                        },
                                    })}
                                >
                                    {row.isExpanded ? <ExpandLessIcon />  : <ExpandMoreIcon />}
                                </span>
                            ) : null,
                        Filter: () => (
                            <input
                                className='disabledFilter'
                                style={{
                                    border: 'none',
                                    borderBottomStyle: 'solid',
                                    borderWidth: '1px',
                                    borderBottomColor: 'rgb(118, 118, 118)',
                                    width: '100%',
                                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                                    color: 'white',
                                }}
                                disabled='disabled'
                            />
                        ),
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'expander',
                        width: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 15 : 20) : 55,
                        minWidth: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 15 : 20) : 30,
                        widthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 15 : 20) : 55,
                        minWidthHeader: isBigScreen3 ? (isMedium3Screen ? 15 : 20) : 30,
                        show: false,
                        Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsExpandedProps }) => <span {...getToggleAllRowsExpandedProps()}></span>,
                        Cell: ({ row }) =>
                            row.canExpand ? (
                                <span
                                    onClick={(e) => {
                                        e.stopPropagation();
                                    }}
                                    {...row.getToggleRowExpandedProps({
                                        style: {
                                            paddingLeft: `${row.depth * 2}rem`,
                                            height: 40,
                                        },
                                    })}
                                >
                                    {row.isExpanded ? <ExpandLessIcon />  : <ExpandMoreIcon /> }
                                </span>
                            ) : null,
                        Filter: () => (
                            <input
                                className='disabledFilter'
                                style={{
                                    border: 'none',
                                    borderBottomStyle: 'solid',
                                    borderWidth: '1px',
                                    borderBottomColor: 'rgb(118, 118, 118)',
                                    width: '100%',
                                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                                    color: 'white',
                                }}
                                disabled='disabled'
                            />
                        ),
                    },
                ],
            }            
        ];
        let isCustomer = user.roles.filter(f => f.name === 'Customer').length > 0;
        
        return isCustomer ? cols.filter(f => f.Header !== 'Expand') : cols;
    }

This is what the table currently looks like

Both dropdowns are activated because in columns both id 'A#' and 'expander'(C#) share the row.isExpanded condition, so I need to separate that. But I don't know how to filter the data for the toggle. Please let me know if I need to post any additional code, I will update the forum if so.
